# Value of type '1-dimensional array of '' cannot be converted to ''

Tags: vb.net

The error below happens on Building, Feature and ListingImage:

> ```
> Error 17  Value of type '1-dimensional array of PropGenie_WebService.Building' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of PropGenie_WebService.Building)'.
> ```

So my webservice uses Listings, in listings you get buildings, features, ListingImages etc.. A building can have an area unit en size as you can see from the code. I have tried to make it arrays but still get this error. I have been stuck on this the whole day and I am really stuck..

My code in webservice:

```
  }, _
         .Features = {New Feature() With { _
             .Name = "Bedrooms", _
             .Count = "2" _
        }}, _
         .Images = {New ListingImage() With { _
             .Caption = "Awesomesauce", _
             .Url = "http://company.com/assets/index_background-84ec0c49973c354e38aea4b19d440e69.jpg" _
        }, New ListingImage() With { _
             .Caption = "Awesomesauce", _
             .Url = "http://company.com/assets/index_background-84ec0c49973c354e38aea4b19d440e69.jpg" _
        }}, _
         .Buildings = {New Building() With { _
             .AreaUnit = "sqm", _
             .AreaValue = 1000 _
        }} _
    }
```

And an example of Building:

```
Public Property AreaUnit() As String
        Get
            Return m_AreaUnit
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_AreaUnit = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_AreaUnit As String
```

And sample from Listings class

```
 Buildings = New List(Of Building)()
        Features = New List(Of Feature)()
        Images = New List(Of ListingImage)()
...
Public Property Buildings() As List(Of Building)
        Get
            Return m_Buildings
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of Building))
            m_Buildings = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

Please let me know if any other code is needed.

What I have tried but still errors

```
}, _
         .Features = New List(Of Feature) from { New Feature(){ With { _     'With Error: Expression Expected
             .Name = "Bedrooms", 
             .Count = "2" _     'Error: Not a member of listings
        }}, _
         .Images = New List(Of ListingImage) From { New ListingImage(){ With { _
             .Caption = "Awesomesauce", _
             .Url = "http://company.com/assets/index_background-84ec0c49973c354e38aea4b19d440e69.jpg" _      'Error: not a member of listings
        }, New ListingImage() With { _
             .Caption = "Awesomesauce", _
             .Url = "http://company.com/assets/index_background-84ec0c49973c354e38aea4b19d440e69.jpg" _
        }}, _
         .Buildings = New List(Of Building) From { New Building(){ With { _
             .AreaUnit = "sqm", _
             .AreaValue = 1000 _
        }} _
    }
```

Comment: the bit about `1 dimensional array` is telling you that you still dont need those trailing parens.  `Buildings = New List(Of Building)()` is an ARRAY of `List(of Building)` - same with `Features` and `Images`.  and you almost never want a prop setter for those

Comment: I am not sure I understand you. Sorry. Or What I should edit

Comment: remove the trailing parens: `Buildings = New List(Of Building)`; you almost never want other code to be able to change or clear your collections, so remove the `m_Buildings = value` from the Property Set (at a minimum - a Collection CLass would be better at preventing that)

Comment: I have removed the `m_Buildings = value` at my `GET/SET` but error is still appearing.

Comment: @Plutonix *Buildings = New List(Of Building)() is an ARRAY of List(of Building)* No, it's not

Comment: When you have code that's looking that intricate, it may be time to separate out the small parts and add them together later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.Buildings =  {New Building() With { _
         .AreaUnit = "sqm", _
         .AreaValue = 1000 _
    }}
```

creates an array of Building, but you need a list:

```
.Buildings = New List(Of Building) From { New Building() With {...}}
```

Comment: Please see original post, I have made changes but got 3 errors

Comment: You have one pair of `{`/`}` to much (between the classname and `with`).